# Cannot get alerts for emails in a shared mailbox that does not have any reply within 20 minutes

Tags: power-automate

We are using Outlook. We have a shared mailbox (Request@domain.com). The whole team shares this mailbox. The customers send in requests to this shared mailbox or sometimes they would just cc the shared mailbox. These emails arrive in the "Inbox" folder. When our team replies to any email they CC the shared mailbox, they go in the "Teams Email" Folder which is a subfolder of "Inbox".

I want to build a power Automate that checks if each and every email that comes in from the customer in the "Inbox" folder has been replied to or not within 20 minutes. if not, send a message to a Microsoft Teams group chat about the email. Here is my progress so far but it seems I am doing something wrong as I am do not get these alerts. overall, I am over complicating the flow.

The flow triggers but does not bring back any value after "Get Emails V3". Another problem is the validation to check if an email is 20 minutes old and does not have any replies just does not seem to work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Update the question with where the flow is dropping out. For example, does your flow trigger at all when an email comes in? If yes, then what happens?

Comment: Yes, the flow triggers but basically does nothing in the get emails section. overall, the flow does not get the 20 minutes reply either.

Comment: When an email is replied to, is it in the Sent Items folder of the Shared Mailbox?

Comment: Hi @SamNseir, the team replies through their own email but CC the mailbox. And we also have a rule where whatever email comes from our domain, send it to "Team Email" Folder.